# Highlighting Via Parameter In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a parameter using Tableau 10.2 on one of my data field name as
"Region". This is a string and i have selected a list option.
To call this i have created 2 calculated fields:
    [Group Highlight] this is one calc field which has name of my parameter.
The other calculated field is
    CASE [Group Highlight]
    WHEN [Assigned Group] THEN [Group Highlight ] ELSE "Others" END

What i am trying to do when a user selects a specific group that region/group should appear in separate color when i will place this field on color by option. However i only get Others.

Comment: There are good ways to highlight things that are more versatile than using parameters. If you have multiple regions with different colours, you can highlight a single region via an action or via the colour legend. but if you select one via a parameter, the best you can do is colour the selected parameter in a binary way (one colour for region=parameter, one for everything else).

Comment: Yes i was able to get the above code working. There was some mis-spelling in the region name, after converting all to Upper case this worked.